# Android Анимация ListView

Tags: android, анимация, listview

Сделал анимированный ListView, используя библиотеку [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations).
Всё работает, но не получается адекватно удалять элементы. Получилось сделать красивое удаление только через DynamicListView.enableSwipeToDismiss..., но при таком использовании элементы удаляются при свайпе, хотя мне нужно по кнопке, а свайп сам мешает, так как при пролистывании TabActivity, в котором и находится ListView, срабатвает свайп ListView и удаляется элемент. Такого не должно быть.

```
   RoleList.enableSwipeToDismiss(
                new OnDismissCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(@NonNull final ViewGroup listView, @NonNull final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                        for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                            adapter.remove(bp.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
private static int position;
public static void animdelete(int positionn, View view) {

   // position=positionn;

    RoleList.dismiss(positionn);
 //   view.startAnimation(animation);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перешёл на recyclerView. Из-за того, что я новичок в программировании на Android перепутал recyclerView c ListView и считал, что recyclerView устарел.